# WPF Mosaic like layout?

Tags: wpf, layout

Does anyone know of a layout control that I can give it multiple controls and tries to organise them on the screen?

I want something like a wrap panel, but the controls have different sizes and ideally I want to minizmise the empty spaces between them.

Answer (score 1):

I am building a workaround class to do that, same reason that your
but if you looking for a paid solution [this guys](http://devexpress.com/) have nice dashboard windows metro style based